# Beta version in Android play store. Where's the opt-in link for testers?

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

How to publish beta test-version in Android play store ?

I'm trying to allow beta test my phonegap build app in the android play store. I already uploaded a signed apk in the beta tab and added a google+ group with some users inside ... but I'm slightly surprised that I cannot find how to install or even find this app on the testers smartphones. I opted myself as user in the group but cant see a link to the app or something like that. Shouldn't the app be already visible to beta users in the app store? Or do I have to push the publish button? The info popup tells:

```
"Your app can only be used by your testers when it is published to Google Play. 
If your app has no production APK then it will only be visible to Alpha and Beta 
testers. The link that your testers can use to opt-in will be displayed here when 
you have published your app."
```

Sounds to me that it should be published. But doesn't it mean that the beta apk will be moved to the published-area and not being then a beta any more? I'm afraid that the app will be then visible to all users in the play store not only for my beta testers.

Could someone explain me how to publish a beta for my testers only?

EDIT:
It seems that everything I need is the opt-in link that is missing. Any idea why?

[image: Missing opt-in link]

Comment: I was a tester in a few apps, so I can tell it from a testers side. I was invited for every app (same g+ account and group) in email, there could I accept to be a tester for that particular app and download the apk if available. Note that after uploading beta app, it will need a couple of hours for the app to be available for testers. Find the link that should be send in email, it has to be there somewhere.

Comment: When you accept being a tester, there is a link at the bottom of the sign-up page :) But your application may not be in the 'draft' stage anymore!

Comment: Thank you guys. It's good to know how the testers part should look a like. I'm simply missing the opt-in link that should be there but isn't. I added a screenshot to demonstrate this problem.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I'm planning to publish an alpha version soon and I was wondering how long will take to appear the link and I see your comment below you are saying that you are still waiting after 5 days!! Thank you

Comment: Nope, unfortunately the beta link didn't show up at all and I give up to wait for it and use instead Testflight for betatesting which is a very convenient way.

Answer (score 63):

In order to be able to get the link to share with your group you have to first press the "Publish" button in the upper right. After doing this you will see the link to share with users appear as brheal shows above.

I'm adding this graphic to the discussion to help clarify exactly which one to press and which to not press.

Per the discussion above I was still a bit worried about pressing the publish button. I just did it and it works.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Chad for this clarification. I wasn't that brave and just  simply avoided this risk by using testflight for the beta test. But I'm sure that you just helped a nation full of people with the same question in mind.

Comment: It seems beta users have to go through the purchase process and 'buy' the app. Beta users are charged but you can go back in and refund the money later.

Comment: I have think there are two ways around this: 1. Add them to the list of license accounts with license testing access. 2. send them the apk directly. This shoudl be the same apk you have on the play store with licensing and obfuscation. 2. b) They can pay and download the apk and you can then refund the charge. The app will continue to work since they are on the list of licnse testers.

One problem with this method is that you need to leave the "License Test Response" set to "LICENSED"

Comment: The fact the publish button is *above* the BETA & ALPHA tabs is *terrible* UX design. Also, it's now at the top-right. (As of the date I'm commenting).

Comment: is publishing to production from beta testing instant? or do we have to wait few hours?

Comment: I am unable to publish it? How can I get the opt-in link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38648707/you-need-to-sign-in-to-your-google-account?noredirect=1#comment64712228_38648707

Comment: OMG I just accidentally published an app that is only ready for Beta testing thanks to Google's terrible design!

Comment: Anyone know where this link is on the latest app store dashboard?  We've created an open Beta, setup a store listing, etc.  But we still get no opt-in link and can see a publish button.

Answer (score 44):

For more clarity I thought I'd share what it looks like. After publishing your beta apk you have to wait up to 24 hours (it took mine about 12) and then go to 'Manage list of testers' in your 'Beta Testing' tab. When it's ready you will see the opt in link available to share:

[image]

Comment: Oh great to see how this popup should look a like. Thank you very much for the helpful screenshot! I also thought to wait long enough - so I'm waiting since 5 days but there was a weekend in between. Hope, there will be an approval from google soon ;/

Comment: Still no change - the link didn't show up. Is there something else I should do? Pushing certain button or something?

Comment: you may not have actually published it. Once you upload the apk there should be a publish option, in the dropdown options maybe. I'm not sure where it shows up now since I've already hit it. Now when I upload a new apk it just lets me publish it from the upload view. I'll try to get a screenshot of it as soon as I can.

Comment: Actually there is a publish button. But I thought that pressing it means making out of the beta the final version and offering it for the public...

Comment: Yeah that made me nervous as well. As long as you don't do the option 'Promote to Prod' in the Actions column it won't go to production. You can 'publish' it and it will be published as a Beta apk. I don't like the wording as well. They should make it very clear that it's not being published to production.

Comment: Yep, this is confusing. Publish button becomes enabled when clicked on extended mode - this causes the production button to change in a drop down list with "publish" inside. So I thought all functions in the same place will be identical. The difference between "publish" and "publish to production" (and also the german version I see) in mimal and can and will be mistaken. Damn bad labeling ;/ Finaly I found the courage to push on "publish" *scared-to-death*

Comment: I just noticed that publishing the app removes it from the beta tab and also the link with the list of beta testers and groups is gone. Should it be this way?

Comment: @Hexodus just clicked the publish button and waiting to appear in the market ( hope only for beta and not to *everyone* ) !

Comment: @mt0s How did it turn out? Was the result as desired?

Comment: Yes, the moment I clicked `publish` it gave me a link to send to testers.

Comment: So does this mean I need to add ALL of the Google play assets (screenshots, texts etc...) before I can send my app to beta testers?

Comment: Yes, you will have to do just enough to make it eligible to publish, but you can certainly just stub them out with anything and change them when you are ready to publish it live.

Comment: quick question, publishing only the beta still counts the days you get featured in Top New Free?
do they start counting from the time you publish your beta or only when you publish a production? Thanks

Comment: Hi, I am unable to get the opt-in link. Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38648707/you-need-to-sign-in-to-your-google-account?noredirect=1#comment64712228_38648707

Answer (score 3):

This is really an issue Google should address ASAP. You enter the console hoping to find the sections but the documentation says something else altogether. I just solved this and found the link, here are the steps updated with the current UI of the console which is not matching the documentation:

1. Open Google Play Console
2. Open your app
3. In the left panel go to **Release management** -> **App releases**
4. Scroll down to **Open track**, **Closed track** or **Internal test track** section according to your case, click **Manage**
5. Go to the section **Manage testers** and click **Internal test**
6. At the bottom you will see the link if everything is properly configured and the app is published.

**VERY IMPORTANT**

- You need to configure the internal test list, I assume that if you
  are looking for the link you've already done this.
- The app needs to be published, remember it takes some hours, otherwise you won´t be able to see the link.

Here are the screenshots:

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not enough points to comment, hence a separate answer.
My suggestion is to upload a new build after setting up the beta testing.

I created a new app and rolled out the Beta version of the app.
After that I enabled the "Closed Beta testing" for a list of users - alas no opt-in link was ever generated.

After scratching my head a bit I released a NEW build which generated the opt-in link immediately.

I figured that enabling the "Closed Beta testing" AFTER the Beta version was released could have caused the issue and is maybe why the UI is constructed the way it is.... just a guess.

Try and release a new build.