# Alpha test build of Unpublished App in PlayStore

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app in PlayStore which is currently unpublished with an old unwanted version of the app in the Production slot.

I've uploaded a new Alpha build of the app with Closed Group alpha testing set up.

Can I confirm - will the users be able to access the app in its unpublished state or will I need to push the app to be published before the Alpha will be downloadable?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

When the app is in alpha only tester can check and download the app version which you put for alpha testing .And if your tester are not able to see that version make sure you have shared them the testing link and they have accepted invitation . If you want to make this version available for everyone you can push the same version directly from alpha to production.

Comment: Answer was not clear at all. Here is for more detail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400059/beta-version-in-android-play-store-wheres-the-opt-in-link-for-testers/19500499#19500499