# Beta Testing Google Developer Account

Tags: android, publish, google-play-console

I wanted to get information on a program of publishing the Beta Testing of my app, but without the publishing on the Store, because they are not willing to carry out any publication.

I will explain which is my problem. I have loaded within the section Beta testing, the apk to send your users to the test.

I have to say that the app is not currently loaded the APK in the Manufacturing section and then that section is empty and that the app is not published.

After loading and have carried out the Rollout in the section of the link in the section “Beta testing”, I see which gives me the following message “An opt-in link will be available here when you publish your app.”

I ask you, therefore, are obliged to publish on the store ? Not having loaded any apk in the manufacturing section, and by changing the status from “unpublished” to “published”, users can still see my app or not see it ?

Thanks to all,
Vincenzo

Answer (score 1):

If you have your APK published to beta testing only (not production)

- if you have an open beta it will be visible in the store for anyone
- if you have a closed beta (only pre-selected beta testers) then it will only be visible in the store to the beta testers

Either way, the opt-in link won't be visible until you publish the app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have your app only in the Beta testing program.

It is possible for the opt-in link not to be there yet. It takes some processing time before this is ready.

In a few hours (up to 24h according to the SO topic below) the link should be available and you should be able to have your beta testers subscribe for your app on the play store.

Check out this SO topic for more info on the beta testing:
[Beta version in Android play store. Where's the opt-in link for testers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400059/beta-version-in-android-play-store-wheres-the-opt-in-link-for-testers)

Comment: But then I confirm that I have the application with a status of "published" but without APK to production upload ?